# Android - grant permanent permission / access to UsbDevice

Tags: android

App is trying to communicate with UsbDevice and to do so it has to get permission from user

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host)

Both ways (explicitly asking user, or trough intent) are working fine - as intended.

But, when device is rebooted - user must allow access to USB device again. If device is attached it will ask ass soon as device boots.

Is there way to get around that? Can we get permission permanently?

It would be great if we can manage this without root / app being system app. But if it is necessary app can be system app.
Also, I would like to do this according to Google / Android guidelines

Comment: any success with this? my only idea was to run `AccessibilityService` which would click on accepting permission button on dialog

Comment: @snachmsm Yes, this is can be achieved with shared user poperty and signing app with platform key. But this also has its pitfalls. Still looking for more elegant, proper way to do it.